# Serving CSS from relative paths that extends above the URL root?

Tags: html, css, browser, cross-browser

I have an html file in:

```
src/test/html/index.html
```

And css in:

```
src/test/css/index.css
```

From the html file the CSS is loaded by doing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/index.css">
```

This works when I run `http-server` from the root project directory and navigate to the page:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/target/test/html/
```

But when serving the html directory contents, such that `index.html` appeard at the root like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

The CSS does not load.  I assume this is because the browser does not understand the navigation (Effectively we are trying to navigate beyond the root path /).

Is there any way to get around this without moving files around such that the CSS will serve via this URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

Comment: No, that is not possible. You can not go above the domain root - that would not even make _sense_. If you want to keep that file system directory structure, you can set up an alias or use rewriting to make a path _below_ the domain root point to that location though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html, Javascript and CSS are 'client side languages.'  The run on the client machine.  PHP, ASP, Ruby etc are server side languages which run on the server.

The issue here is that you are giving the html the link to the css file.  As a result, when the html is being processed on the client side, it doesn't have permissions (and cant be given) to access any files outwith the public directories on the server.